# Combining multiple foreach loops

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to make to make this work correctly.  I am using 2 date pickers to change the date on a text file.  The issue I am running into is that when I click on the button to run the 3 functions (jdate, pdate and flip) the output text file duplicates the entries instead of reading each line in the file and then applying each of the 3 functions before printing the line.

Any suggestions I can try to fix this?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            jdate();
        }

        private void jdate()
        {
            string tmp = "", tmp2 = "", tmp3 = "";
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(ComboValue + ".txt"))
            {
                tmp = line.Remove(24, 8).Insert(24, jDatePicker.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
                sb.Append(tmp);


                tmp2 = line.Remove(32, 8).Insert(32, pDatePicker.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
                sb.Append(tmp2);
 

                if (line.Substring(52, 1).Equals("+"))
                {
                    StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder(line);
                    sbLine[52] = '-';
                    tmp3 = sbLine.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder(line);
                    sbLine[52] = '+';
                    tmp3 = sbLine.ToString();
                }
                //sb.Append(tmp + tmp2 + tmp3);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(ComboValue + "-Reversal.txt", sb.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it sounds like all you need is one method that does what all 3 of these do inside of a single foreach loop.  Do all of your logic for the substringing and allocate them to new variables, then concatenate it all together afterwards and write the line back to your output file.

Comment: Do I still need to include this line after each substring?                             
                   sb.Append(tmp + Environment.NewLine);

Comment: You're adding the entire contents of the file to `sb` three separate times. You could do it all in one loop. Replace the date at index 24 with `jDatePicker.Value`, replace the date at index 32 with `pDatePicker.Value`, flip the sign at index 52, then append the modified line to `sb`. After the `foreach` that iterates the lines of the file, call `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: @RashmiPatel - use `sb.AppendLine(tmp)` instead of `sb.Append(tmp + Envirnoment.NewLine)`

Comment: Also, use `System.IO.Path.Build()` to define parts which does a lot of checks compared to you doing `path + name` type of operations.

Comment: I made the following changes based on suggestion but I think I missing something. It still is generating a new line for each check (dates and flip sign).  Do I modify the  original code in the question to show my work with what I updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily using multiple appends, and missing adding tmp3 all together:

```
private void jdate()
        {
            string tmp = "", tmp2 = "", tmp3 = "";
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(ComboValue + ".txt"))
            {
                tmp = line
.Remove(24, 8).Insert(24, jDatePicker.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"));


                tmp2 = tmp.Remove(32, 8).Insert(32, pDatePicker.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"));
 

                StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder(tmp2);
                if (tmp2.Substring(52, 1).Equals("+"))
                {
                    sbLine[52] = '-';
                }
                else
                {
                    sbLine[52] = '+';
                }
                tmp3 = sbLine.ToString();
                sb.Append(tmp3);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(ComboValue + "-Reversal.txt", sb.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks.   Is there a event for the exit button on the windows form (upper right next to maximize)?  when I close my form1 using that button, it opens form1.

Comment: Ask your new questions on a new question after marking answer to your current question. That button closes the form.